# Unable to resolve dependency tree Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

I am trying to install MDX in my Gatsby project with all its corresponding dependencies by typing the following command (from official Gatsby docs):

`npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1`

The error below shows what happens next.

[image]

Ok, this error seems to be happening to more people and I found an answer that partly solves the issue. Typing `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1 --legacy-peer-deps` will result in the packages actually being installed, however, whenever typing `npm i` next, I get a similar error:

[image]

In other words, the problem remains. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing them peer dependencies flag raised?

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1 --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. Get the same errors over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found an answer to my problem. It turned out that MDX does not support React 18. After downgrading to React 17 all problems were solved.

Comment: That's not an ideal solution whatsoever. Modifying the core version of your application (like changing React's major version does) can't produce more issues than it solves, besides modifying the behavior of some components (React 18 is really a major upgrade). The peer dependencies are intended to bypass this version limitations by providing the right version for the dependencies that they need (if MDX needs React 17 they will be installed as is) but without modifying your project version, allowing you to use React's 18 features in your project and React 17 to your dependencies